# Bootstrap slider not giving the expected result

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel, slide

I was trying to make a carousel for my website using Bootstrap, but the carousel just gives me this icon:

[image]

My Google dev tools did not give me errors, the same can be said for Pycharm; no errors. Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container">
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="C:\Users\pert\PycharmProjects\milestonewebsite\images\one.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="C:\Users\pert\PycharmProjects\milestonewebsite\images\two.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="C:\Users\pert\PycharmProjects\milestonewebsite\images\three.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: also, don't get confused by the image not loaded picture, that is the actual thing that it returned

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found out the problem, for some reson, my computer only accepted gif links, now it is working properly